# Deprecated method addValidation and class CallbackValidator in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I have a problem. I need to validate a field that is not in entity in form type class. Previously I used this code:

```
$builder->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form){
    if (!$form['t_and_c']->getData()) {
        $form->addError(new FormError('Please accept the terms and conditions in order to registe'));
    }
}))
```

But since Symfony 2.1 method `addValidator` and class `CallbackValidator` are deprecated. Does anyone know what I should use instead?

Comment: `CallbackValidator` is not deprecated, as a matter of fact, it's [tagged as `@api`](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/Constraints/CallbackValidator.php).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done it in this way:

```
add('t_and_c', 'checkbox', array(
            'property_path' => false,
            'constraints' => new True(array('message' => 'Please accept the terms and conditions in order to register')),
            'label' => 'I agree'))
```

Comment: use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True;

Answer (score 2):

The interface `FormValidatorInterface` was deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 2.3.

> If you implemented custom validators using this interface, you can
>   substitute them by event listeners listening to the
>   `FormEvents::POST_BIND` (or any other of the `*BIND` events). In case
>   you used the CallbackValidator class, you should now pass the callback
>   directly to `addEventListener`.

via https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#deprecations

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for help changing their validators to event subscribers (as it is slightly different to normal subscribers) follow this:

### Step 1

Change:

`$builder->addValidator(new AddNameFieldValidator());`
to
`$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddNameFieldSubscriber());`

### Step 2

Replace your validator class (and all the namespaces) to a subscriber class.
Your subscriber class should look like the following:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/EventListener/AddNameFieldSubscriber.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AddNameFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::POST_BIND => 'postBind');
    }

    public function postBind(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->addError(new FormError('oh poop'))
    }
}
```

**You do not need to register the subscriber in a service file (yml or otherwise)**

---

Reference:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Answer has been modified.